# Multiple paging scrollviews - Swift

Tags: swift

I have multiple paging scrollviews embedded in a single view controller.

I have the first page controller hooked up to:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    var pageWidth:CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame)
    var currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1
    self.myPageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}
```

however the second scrollview when scrolled changes the first page control.

Both scrollviews work independently of each other (this is working) but I can't work out how to change the second page controller on the second scrollview.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is unsure, I achieved the results by first checking what height the scrollView was and if it was < what I knew one of the scrollViews is then I updated the appropriate page control.